# Periodicity of Bell numbers modulo $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, bell-numbers

After doing some numerical simulations, I rediscovered that the Bell numbers are periodic modulo $n$, that is to say we have the following identities :

\begin{align}
B_{n+3}   &= B_n\mod{2} \\\\
B_{n+13}  &= B_n\mod{3} \\\\
B_{n+12}  &= B_n\mod{4} \\\\
B_{n+781} &= B_n\mod{5} \\\\
&\vdots
\end{align}

In fact, I realized that there is a Wikipedia chapter that talks about [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Modular_arithmetic) and an a [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A054767) for all the periods modulo $n$. The Wikipedia chapter claims that for a prime $p$ the period modulo $p$ must divide $(p^p-1)/(p-1)$

**Questions :**

1. How can we prove such identities and their generalizations to higher modulos ?
2. How can we indeed prove that the Bell numbers are periodic modulo $p$ with a period that divides $(p^p-1)/(p-1)$ ?

Comment: How about going to the links provided by Wikipedia? They provide at least $4$ very nice references that probably answer all your questions, ref. $15-18$.